# bash script to install and start tomcat on rhel 9 cant use systemctl

Tags: tomcat, rhel, systemctl

1. have installed Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.2 (Plow) on ec2 instance in AWS
2. wrote a bash script to install tomcat 9 and start the service automatically
3. the tomcat.service is getting written in /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
4. however after running the script ends with below error lines
5. getenforce shows 'Enforcing'

File content replaced with custom code for context.xml.
File content replaced with custom code for tomcat-users.xml.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tomcat.service → /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service.
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xeu tomcat.service" for details.

manual start of tomcat is working as desired, but systemctl is failing.